# Use Kindle for PC Anonymously

Tags: anonymity

I would like to read Kindle books anonymously, to protect my identity from being used against me (for example, employment opportunities, reputtaion, etc).  I have tried using Tor and the kindle cloud reader, but Amazon will not let me download some books.

Can VMWare "sandbox" me from being identified, if I find a way to also use Kindle for PC app through Tor?

Forgive me, but I am not very tech savvy.

Comment: What information are you trying to hide from whom? Clearly if you're buying books from Amazon, then Amazon knows exactly who you are. And since your communications with Amazon is over HTTPS, all your ISP could determine is that "Mr. Anonymous Browser is browsing the Amazon web site". Nobody else is involved.

Comment: You can pay for books anonymously on Amazon.  The problem is that I somehow need to use the Kindle for PC app, not just the browser.  Does the app use HTTPS as well?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - yes, an app uses HTTPS too and even more: exactly the same infrastructure. If you're able to use VMWare "one-time used" machine - yes, browsing anonymously you will be a way more private via separate isolated VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you bought any book on Kindle. There's no way to become anonymous any more. Because already **Amazon** took your credit card information. They know you, but you can use Tails Operating Systems, or proxy for becoming anonymous online.